# How to download a file in angular 4 without hard-coding file name?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript, spring-boot

Here is the code:

```
importedSaveAs(blob, 'somefile.txt');
```

In this case I have hard-coded the file name: I want to know how to make it dynamic. I am able to see the file name in response header but not able to access it here.

Comment: are you able to get response header in a variable ?

Comment: I am new to angular. So I wanted to know how it can be done as it's the requirement which I got. I saw the response in postman. I am getting only a piece of code where its been hard-coded.

Comment: check my answer below, might you get headers

Answer (score 0):

At first, call the API to get the data

```
 this._http.get(requestURL)   // you can do it in your own way
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData);
```

Once you gets the data , pass it to the extract method

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
 let name = res.headers()

    importedSaveAs(blob, name);  

    }
```

now, **name** is dynamically passing to your custom save function.

Comment: I'll try this out.